# jQuery multiple date generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have simple form with start date and end date. I want to achieve that when I select start date the end date would be generated automatically (+3 months). The problem is I have a green button which generates another couple of date inputs. I need that script to work on dynamically generated inputs they have same class and name, but can have different values. Because now it's work on first inputs and doesn't work for the next who can have different start date so automatically it would have another end date.

```js
$('#skaicius').val(2);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#duomenys').submit(function() {
    $('#skaicius').val($('.fieldGroup').length * 1 + 1);
  })
  //papildomu pareigu limitas
  var maxGroup = 10;
  //$('#skaicius').val(2);
  //papildomu pareigu pridejimas
  $(".prideti").click(function() {
    if ($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup) {
      var fieldHTML = '<div class="row form-group fieldGroup">' + $(".fieldGroupCopy").html() + '</div>';
      $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);

    } else {
      alert('Viršintas didžiausias papildomų pareigų skaičius.');
    }
  });



  //papildomu pareigu salinimas
  $("body").on("click", ".salinti", function() {
    $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();

  });



  // Generates start and end date

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.darbo_pradzia').change(function() {
      let date = new Date($(this).val());
      let newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3));
      var day = ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
      var month = ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      var formatted = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
      $('.bandomasis_laikotarpis').val(formatted);
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row form-group fieldGroup">
    <h4>Darbuotojo pareigos</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-success prideti" title="[Pridėti pareigas]"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></a></div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Darbo pradžia</label>
      <input type="date" name="darbo_pradzia[]" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
      <input type="date" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis[]" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- Papildomos pareigos -->
  <div class="row form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <h4>Papildomos pareigos</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-danger salinti" title="[Šalinti]"><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></a></div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Darbo pradžia</label>
      <input type="date" name="darbo_pradzia[]" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
      <input type="date" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis[]" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Papildomos pareigos pabaiga -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several remarks:

- don't put several "`$(document).ready`"
- use '`clone`' to copy your elements, with "`true, true`" to bind events
- use DOM tree to find the elements you want to modify.

```js
$('#skaicius').val(2);

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.darbo_pradzia').on('change', function() {
    var elt = $(this)
    let date = new Date(elt.val());
    let newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3));
    var day = ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var formatted = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
    elt.closest('.form-group').find('.bandomasis_laikotarpis').val(formatted);
  });

  $('#duomenys').submit(function() {
    $('#skaicius').val($('.fieldGroup').length * 1 + 1);
  })
  //papildomu pareigu limitas
  var maxGroup = 10;
  //$('#skaicius').val(2);
  //papildomu pareigu pridejimas
  $(".prideti").click(function() {
    if ($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup) {
      $('#fieldGroupCopy').clone(true, true).appendTo('#container').show()
    } else {
      alert('Viršintas didžiausias papildomų pareigų skaičius.');
    }
  });

  //papildomu pareigu salinimas
  $("body").on("click", ".salinti", function() {
    $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row form-group fieldGroup">
    <h4>Darbuotojo pareigos</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-success prideti" title="[Pridėti pareigas]"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></a></div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Darbo pradžia</label>
      <input type="date" name="darbo_pradzia[]" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
      <input type="date" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis[]" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- Papildomos pareigos -->
  <div class="row form-group" id="fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <h4>Papildomos pareigos</h4>
    <div style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tbtn-print btn-sm btn-danger salinti" title="[Šalinti]"><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></a></div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="dpradzia">Darbo pradžia</label>
      <input type="date" name="darbo_pradzia[]" class="form-control darbo_pradzia">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="text-black" for="bandomasis_laikotarpis">Bandomasis laikotarpis</label>
      <input type="date" name="bandomasis_laikotarpis[]" class="form-control bandomasis_laikotarpis">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Papildomos pareigos pabaiga -->

</div>
```

Comment: sorry, this one is bad solution because, id gives the same id for multiple generated forms and another problem i need the same class when generated because i'am counting them.

Comment: You didn't precise this in your question, you can't unaccept the answer... And what ID and what class are you talking about? This is not serious...